# A decorator to replace specific string in function to another string

Tags: python, decorator

Is it possible to do like this ?

```
def my_func():
    my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
    my_str = 'abc'
```

If I pass A to decorator -> replace 'abc' to 'xxx' in function, pass B -> yyy

@decorator('abc')

```
def my_func():
    my_list = ['xxx', 'def', 'ghi']
    my_str = 'xxx'
```

I don't know whether it's possible or not.

How can I do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a decorator that uses `ast.NodeTransformer` to modify any string node with the target value with the given replacement in the function's AST:

```
import ast
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent

class Replace(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, target, replacement):
        self.target = target
        self.replacement = replacement

    def visit_Str(self, node):
        if node.s == self.target:
            node.s = self.replacement
        return node

    # remove 'replace' from the function's decorator list to avoid re-decorating during exec
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        node.decorator_list = [
            decorator for decorator in node.decorator_list
            if not isinstance(decorator, ast.Call) or decorator.func.id != 'replace'
        ]
        self.generic_visit(node)
        return node

def replace(target, repl):
    def decorator(func):
        tree = Replace(target, repl).visit(ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(func))))
        ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
        scope = {}
        exec(compile(tree, inspect.getfile(func), "exec"), func.__globals__, scope)
        return scope[func.__name__]
    return decorator
```

so that:

```
@replace('abc', 'xxx')
def my_func():
    my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
    my_str = 'abc'
    print(my_list, my_str)

my_func()
```

outputs:

```
['xxx', 'def', 'ghi'] xxx
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ValuableLimeVideogames

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to replace the code object of a function with a decorator thereby replacing constants inside of it, but it's unlikely to be the solution you actually want to go with.

This would get unmaintainable at nearly any scale as you'd have large sections looking like:

```py
# Note, this is python 3.x specific
CodeType(
    argcount,             #   integer
    kwonlyargcount,       #   integer
    nlocals,              #   integer
    stacksize,            #   integer
    flags,                #   integer
    codestring,           #   bytes
    consts,               #   tuple
    names,                #   tuple
    varnames,             #   tuple
    filename,             #   string
    name,                 #   string
    firstlineno,          #   integer
    lnotab,               #   bytes
    freevars,             #   tuple
    cellvars,             #   tuple
)
```

In which you need to make copies from the original code object, modifying them to your intent.

A better solution to this sort of problem would be to allow passing the string to the function as a parameter. If you needed the function to later be callable without the string present, you could use a partial (see [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial))

Comment: Thanks for your advice and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Decorator can't change logic inside of your function. You can either do operation on arguments or whatever you are returning. In your case you can use post decorator

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean of "post decorator". Can you explain it?